# Sticky navigation and the wpadminbar

Tags: css

I have got a site with a sticky header navigation. The problem is that when I am logged in, the `wpadminbar` falls over the navigation.

The code of my navigation is:

```
<div class="container" id ="main">

    <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
....
```

As you can see I use Bootstrap. 
Is there a way to get the `wpadminbar` not to lay over my navigaion?

Comment: have you tried z-index for your navigation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to keep the `wpadminbar` from overlaying your navigation bar by using either JavaScript or a combination of `PHP` and `CSS`.

I would add this php to the *header.php* file of your theme:

```
<?php if ( is_admin_bar_showing() ) { ?>
    <style>
        .my-nav-bar {
            position: absolute;
            top: [wpadminbar-height]px;
        }
    </style>
<?php } ?>
```

Basically, position absolute your navigation below the `wpadminbar` when it's visible.

The other option to move your navigation below the `wpadminbar` is to use JavaScript to get the height of the `wpadminbar` and add it to the `top` CSS property of your navigation container.

OR

If your navigation is positioned absolute and nested inside a `div` that is parallel to the `wpadminbar`, you could add this to your CSS:

```
.container {
    position: relative;
}
.admin-bar .container {
    position: relative;
    padding-top: [wpadminbar-height]px;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

WordPress has a class it outputs if you're using the `body_class()` function (which you should be!) that indicates if the admin bar is showing: `admin-bar`. Therefore, there's no php or JS needed. I'm assuming you're using `position: fixed;` for the `.navbar-fixed-top`. If so, just add this to your theme's stylesheet:

```
.admin-bar .navbar-fixed-top {
    top: 32px; /* if it already has a top value, add 32px to it */
}
```

Also note that the "mobile" menu is taller (46px). If the site has people editing with their phones or tablets, you may need to add another style to account for that:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 782px) {
    .admin-bar .navbar-fixed-top {
        top: 46px; /* if it already has a top value, add 46px to it */
    }
}
```

Or flip those rules and use min-width if you want to take a mobile-first styles approach.

Answer (score 0):

```php
<?php if ( is_admin_bar_showing() ) { ?>
    <style>
        nav {
            position: fixed;
            top: 32px;
        }
        @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
            #wpadminbar {
                position: fixed;
            }
        }
        
    </style>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: This is an alternative to the code in Kevin Vess's answer, to go in header.php? In the <head> block?

Comment: Why is this better than his version? I guess it's specific to some theme has has the 768px breakpoint too?